# Dive into the Dockerfile of nginx parent image

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to understand the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/d039609e3a537df4e15a454fdb5a004d519e9a11/mainline/debian/Dockerfile) of nginx official Docker image. I am focusing on the following lines:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
COPY 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh /docker-entrypoint.d
```

I am playing locally with Docker Desktop. If my Dockerfile has only the following line:

```
FROM nginx
```

and building my own nginx image, then `what is the build context for the Dockerfile` of nginx Docker image? My issue is I cannot understand where the files:

```
docker-entrypoint.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
```

are living and where are they copied from?

Same question is applied to [Ubuntu](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/fbca80af7960ffcca085d509c20f53ced1697ade/focal/Dockerfile) image

Comment: Both files are located in the same directory as the `Dockerfile` you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build context is always the directory you give to the build command, and it usually contains the `Dockerfile` directly in that directory.

```bash
docker build ./build-context-directory
```

```yaml
# Docker Compose syntax
build: ./build-context-directory
```

```yaml
build:
  context: ./build-context-directory
```

The two important things about the context directory are that it is transferred to the Docker daemon as the first step of the build process, and you can never `COPY` or `ADD` anything outside the context directory into the image (excepting `ADD`'s ability to download URLs).

When your Dockerfile starts with a `FROM` line

```bash
FROM nginx
```

Docker includes a pre-built binary copy of that image as the base of your image.  It does not repeat the steps in the original Dockerfile, and you do not need the build-context directory of that image to build a new image based on it.

So a typical Nginx-based image hosting only static files might look like

```bash
FROM nginx
COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY static/ /usr/share/nginx/html/static/
# Get EXPOSE, ENTRYPOINT, CMD from base image; no need to repeat them
```

which you can run with only your application's HTML content but not any of the Nginx-specific details you quote in the question.